# How to report own memory usage C++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, printing

I need to print own aplication memory usage in C++ (C++11) to find memory leak.
I use only shared_ptr but my program take 4GB, input is 1GB output ~0,1GB.

I have one big for

```
for (const std::string & file_name : *files){
    try{some_instructions_with_shared_ptr_here}}
```

Oudsie this for I have only small data structures, inside only shared_ptr.
It may be problem with other classes or data structures so I want to know when memory leak.

Comment: Can you use valgrind? I think clang has a tool for this too. Otherwise you'll probably have to instrument this yourself, AFAIK theres no "easy" way to do this.

Comment: That's actually OS dependent, availability of something like `sbrk()` respectively.

Comment: I can, thx. Let's try...

Answer (score 1):

Using shared_ptr is not leak free mechanism. If you have cycles in your shared_ptr pointees, then then the heap will never be freed.
Neither will valgrind detect it.

Perhaps using setrlimit to limit your apps resources, and see with gdb where it crashes will give you some hints.